# Etiquette when writing a recommendation for a manager on LinkedIn?

Tags: relationships, manager, recommendation-letter

Recently one of my old managers told me he is leaving the company. He taught me a lot of things during my time here and I really wanted to give him a recommendation on his Linkedin (even if it might not do much).

I was wondering if there was any etiquette of what employee would write for a recommendation for his/her manager? Is it weird to do that? What would be some things I could highlight that would make it a good recommendation? Should I talk to him first about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unusual at all, if anything it's becoming commonplace. If it's not too much effort I would check with them that they're ok with you leaving something on their public profile - just make sure it doesn't sound like you're doing this to seek approval from them and that your intentions are in their interest.

When writing your recommendation be sure to avoid company specific topics or sensitive information. Write things regarding their professional manner, for example, something like:

> I greatly enjoyed working with Dave. I found him well organized and he
>   always communicated tasks and deadlines with me in a clear and
>   professional manner.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I wasn't sure if there were some things as an employee that wouldn't be as valuable to highlight and if I should focus more on his role as someone who managed me? Or if I should talk about character, etc.